# GAE Python 3: Static files are not loading on localhost but do load when deployed online

Tags: python-3.x, flask, localhost, google-app-engine-python, static-files

I am trying to migrate a Google App Engine Standard Flask web app from Python 2.7 to Python 3. It works perfectly when deployed to appspot but I'm still experiencing issues while running a local dev server.

The issue is that when running on the local dev server my app is unable to find my static files. I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` and it's against my jquery-3.3.1.min.js: file. I'm reasonably sure that what's happening is that it's trying to find my JQuery file, fails, receives a 404 error html page, and throws a syntax error because it's expecting a JavaScript file and not HTML.

My JQuery file isn't the only static file affected. For example, my CSS isn't loading and my app can't find my local images.

Here are some code snippets:

app.yaml

```
runtime: python38
instance_class: F4

automatic_scaling:
  max_concurrent_requests: 30

handlers:
- url: /_ah/start
  script: auto

- url: /app_shared/app_setup/app_style/*
  static_dir: app_shared/app_setup/app_style

- url: /app_shared/app_setup/app_images/*
  static_dir: app_shared/app_setup/app_images

- url: /app_shared/app_static/jquery/v_3_3_1/*
  static_dir: app_shared/app_static/jquery/v_3_3_1

- url: /app_shared/app_static/util/*
  static_dir: app_shared/app_static/util

- url: .*
  script: auto

error_handlers:
  - file: app_code/templates/errors/default.htm

  - error_code: timeout
    file: app_code/templates/errors/408_timeout.htm
```

h_main_header_menu.htm (this is within the head tag)

```
<script src="/app_shared/app_static/jquery/v_3_3_1/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the hierarchy to the JQuery file from the root of the project: app_shared/app_static/jquery/v_3_3_1_jquery-3.3.1.min.js

To run the local dev server I follow Google's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#windows). So I run it with the commands `venv\Scripts\activate` followed by `python main.py`.

Does anybody know what's going wrong here? I'm at a loss. Any help here is appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to rename my app_shared folder to static. You can find Flask documentation on it [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#static-files)